# Reset filter values when switching between lists

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a `react-admin` App with multiple list resources and would want to only clear the filter when I change between lists (switching between companies/rules/lookups). Currently I am using the solution shown in `RuleList.js` for each list (RuleFilter part). This however also resets the filter every time you show/edit an element in the list. I don't know if there is a way to detect when you click between companies/rules/lookups that you could use to clear the filter.

App.js

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin'

import dataProvider from './dataProvider'

import companies from './companies'
import rules from './rules'
import lookups from './lookups'

const App = () => (
  <Admin
    dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="companies" {...companies} />
    <Resource name="rules" {...rules} />
    <Resource name="lookups" {...lookups} />
  </Admin>
)

export default App
```

RuleList.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, EditButton } from 'react-admin'

const RuleFilter = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { setFilters } = props
    return () => setFilters({ regex: '' })
  }, [])

  return (
    <Filter {...props}>
      <TextInput label="Search" source="regex" alwaysOn />
    </Filter>
  )
}

const RuleList = (props) => {    
  return (
    <List {...props}
      filters={<RuleFilter />}
      exporter={false}>
      <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
        <TextField source="id" />
        <TextField source="regex" />
        <EditButton />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  )
}

export default RuleList
```

index.js for Rule

```
import RuleList from'./RuleList'
import RuleEdit from './RuleEdit'
import RuleCreate from './RuleCreate'

const rules = {
  list: RuleList,
  edit: RuleEdit,
  create: RuleCreate,
}

export default rules
```

[Clear the search field when clicking companies or rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS11n.png)

Comment: Is there a way to determine that your list is changed ?

Comment: Can you explain your question bit more? where is your list? can you provide more code

Comment: @Shyam Don't know, quite new to react-admin myself.

Comment: @PratikRathi Tried to explain my question a bit more and provided more code, please do tell if it made it more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use redux-persist, and save your filters in Store,
   OR
2. Use localStorage to save your filters

Comment: It is `AsyncStorage` in react

Comment: @TechySharnav huh?  In react-native maybe!

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, I meant react-native